# Why does istringstream throw error at the end of the string?

Tags: c++

im having an issue, where this for loop throws an std::length_error when the end of the string is reached.

```
TileLayer* MapParser::ParseTileLayer(TiXmlElement* xmlLayer, TilesetList tilesets, int tilesize, int rowcount, int colcount) {
TiXmlElement* data;

for (TiXmlElement* e = xmlLayer->FirstChildElement(); e!=nullptr; e=e->NextSiblingElement()) {
    if (e->Value() == std::string("data")) {
        data = e;
        break;
    }
}

// Parse Layer tile map
std::string matrix(data->GetText());
std::istringstream iss(matrix);
std::string id;

TileMap tilemap(rowcount, std::vector<int> (colcount, 0));
for (int row = 0; row < rowcount; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < colcount; col++) {
        getline(iss, id, ',');
        std::stringstream convertor(id);
        convertor >> tilemap[row][col];
        std::cout << tilemap[row][col] << std::endl;

        if (!iss.good())
            break;
    }
}

return (new TileLayer(tilesize, rowcount, colcount, tilemap, tilesets));

}
```

and my xml is a tmx file generated by the tiled tile map editor. the extraction of the data works just fine

Comment: Is the last column followed by a `,`?

Comment: You are not checking if `getline(iss, id, ',')` fails before using `id`.  You should `break` the loop immediately if `getline()` fails, not after doing work on an invalid `id` value.

Comment: `data` might be uninitialised

Comment: The Last column isnt followed by a ,

Comment: And I check if getline() was successful with if(getline(iss, I’d, ‘,’)) right? @Remy Lebeau

Comment: @EikePetersen Yes.  Or, you can put the `getline()` in your `for` loop itself: `for (int col = 0; (col < colcount) && getline(iss, id, ','); col++) { ... }`